# PHP Issue: Delete Button to be echoed in Table rows GET/POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which selects the results from a database table, with each record there is a Button echoed (DeleteButton). I would like this delete button to delete THE SELECTED ROw (RECORD).
My code is presented below, I have narrowed the issue down the 'id' not being POST/GET correctly. I think the form is not passing the id correctly. Can somebody help?

The Form In A Table Cell:

```
echo "<td>"
.'
<form id="DeleteUser" action="DeleteUser.php" method"post">
<input type"text" name="id" value=" '.$row['user_id'].' " hidden />
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
'.
"</td>";
echo '</td>';
```

The Delete Statement (DeleteUser) (DeleteUser.php) :

```
<?php


$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sissi',$_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();


?>
```

Comment: please post the HTML generated by PHP code above

Comment: The php generates a blank html code.

Comment: You are specifying the form submission method as POST in the form, but trying to read the value from `$_GET` in `DeleteUser.php`; it should be `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first parameter on the `$stmt->bind_param` statement has 5 different parameters.  You're only passing one.  Change it to this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

You have to make sure `$_GET['id']` is int value also.

On your `<input type"text" name="id" value=" '.$row['user_id'].' " hidden />` line, remove the spaces around value= for the concatenation.  So you have `value="'.$row['user_id'].'"`.

I would also suggest having some kind of check in place to make sure that *I* can't go in and delete a different user just by inputting a different number in there, random or otherwise.